# Cleanup MovieClips on Scene Change in ActionScript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

```
    for(i=0;i<itemLength;i++)
    {
        duplicateMovieClip("tvmenuitem", "tvmenuitem"+i, i);
```

...

However when I change the scene using: gotoAndPlay('main',1);

The main scene is overlayed with all the MovieClips I had in the previous scene.

How can I automagically clean them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store references to the created clips when you generate them:

```
// store your clip references here
var clips:Array = [];

for(i=0;i<itemLength;i++)
{
    // create you duplicated clip and store a reference in your clips array
    var dupe:MovieClip = duplicateMovieClip("tvmenuitem", "tvmenuitem"+i, i);
    clips.push(dupe);
}
```

and then use the `removeMovieClip` method to destroy the clips when neccessary:

```
// loop through the clips array and destroy the clips in your array
for(i=0, l=clips.length; i<l; i++)
{
    clips[i].removeMovieClip();
}

// reset the array
clips = [];
```

Comment: is there a on scene change event?

Comment: not sure, haven't used scenes in a long time. you could always put some AS in the first frame of your scene to clean up old clips references. you might have to stick the `clips` variable in the global scope '_root.clips = []` or something like that. kinda ugly, but coding in the timeline isn't supposed to be pretty :)

Comment: So how should I code then? I'm new to flash. What do you use instead of scenes?

Comment: it all depends on what you are making. scenes work well for story based animations with minimal scripting control. the typical dev-centric workflow is to assign a document class to a project and direct things with code, using the library to store assets and animations that do not make sense to generate without the IDE's drawing/animation tools. there is no sole correct way to go about things, however think about how you plan on maintaing your project as you are building it, so you aren't pulling your hair out a month from now searching for a code snippet on a keyframe somewhere :) cheers.